# Postgres - Geospatial Search in LINQ or SQL with PostGis

Tags: sql, postgresql, linq, geospatial, postgis

I am using PostGis to search for all points within a given range, relative to a given origin. I am looking at all the documentation provided by PostGis but can't seem to figure out how would I come up with a solution for this?

My location table looks like this:

```
Id         - INT(11)  
Longitude  - DOUBLE  
Latitude   - DOUBLE   
Address    - LONGTEXT  
City       - LONGTEXT   
Region     - LONGTEXT  
Country    - LONGTEXT
```

The inputs would be `Longitude`, `Latitude` and a `Range` (as in kilometers or miles).

What I'm hoping is to receive an output of all the records that are within the `Range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

PostGIS relies on coordinates embedded in fields of type `geometry` or `geography`. That being said, your table structure shouldn't store the coordinates into two distinct `double precision` fields, but in a single one.

If you still can change the table structure, just add a new geometry column into your table:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('your_schema','your_table','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

And to create geometries out of your `longitude` and `latitude` columns you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE your_table
SET geom = ST_MakePoint(Longitude, Latitude);
```

After that you might want to create an index, e.g. ..

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING GIST (geom);
```

.. and query it using [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom,
                 ST_MakePoint(input_lon, input_lat),input_distance)
```

Keep in mind that `geometry` and `geography` have different units of measurement. See this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445534/how-to-configure-postgresql-with-postgis-to-calculate-distances/52446455#52446455) or the [`documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) for more details.

If you're not able to change the table structure, you'd have to stick to the solution posted by @Michael Entin, but keep in mind that there will be an unnecessary overhead to create `geometry` or `geography` values in query time, and you also will **not** be able to index them, possibly making queries much slower!

Good luck.

Further reading:

- [`ST_MakePioint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [`AddGeometryColumn`](https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! Yes I went through the documentation again while waiting for somebody to answer. I was thinking of  something between ST_Distance and ST_Within, and then voila, I found ST_DWithin.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :-) if you're wondering about `ST_Distance`, you  might wanna check my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388 cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It is trivial with PostGIS, something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    Geography(ST_MakePoint(Longitude, Latitude)),
    Geography(ST_MakePoint(@Longitude, @Latitude)),
    @Range * 1000)
```

Here @Range is in km, so I multiplied by 1000 to get meters used in geography computations. Note that the query might be slow if you have a lot of data. To make it faster: add Geography-typed column to the table - same as first argument of `ST_DWithin`, and use it instead of this argument in the query. You would also need to create a spatial index for this table.